# how can i show the other data below the grid

Tags: extjs, grid

I am using this article of architecture http://blog.extjs.eu/know-how/writing-a-big-application-in-ext/

This is my grid file

```
Application.DashBoardGrid = Ext.extend(Ext.grid.GridPanel, {
     border:false
    ,fromdate:''
    ,todate : '' 
    ,initComponent:function() {
        var store =new Ext.data.JsonStore({
                // store configs
                autoDestroy: true,
                autoLoad :true,
                url: 'api/index.php?_command=getresellerscount&fromdate='+this.fromdate+'&todate='+this.todate,
                storeId: 'getresellerscount',
                // reader configs
                root: 'cityarray',
                idProperty: 'cityname',
                fields: [
                    {name: 'cityname'},
                    {name: 'totfollowup'},
                    {name: 'totcallback'},
                    {name: 'totnotintrested'},
                    {name: 'totdealsclosed'},
                    {name: 'totcallsreceived'},
                    {name: 'totcallsentered'},
                    {name: 'totresellerregistered'},
                    {name: 'countiro'},
                    {name: 'irotransferred'},
                    {name: 'irodeferred'}
                ]
            });
            console.log(store);
        var config = {
            store:store
            ,columns: [
                {
                    id       :'cityname',
                    header   : 'City Name', 
                    width    : 120, 
                    sortable : true, 
                    dataIndex: 'cityname'
                },
                {
                    id       :'countiro',
                    header   : ' Total Prospect', 
                    width    : 100, 
                    sortable : true, 
                    dataIndex: 'countiro'
                    ,renderer : this.linkiroRenderer
                },
                 {
                    id       :'irotransferred',
                    header   : 'Calls Transfered By IRO', 
                    height : 50,
                    width    : 100, 
                    sortable : true, 
                    dataIndex: 'irotransferred'
                    ,renderer : this.linkiroRenderer
                },
                {
                    id       :'irodeferred',
                    header   : ' Calls Deferred By IRO', 
                    width    : 100, 
                    sortable : true, 
                    dataIndex: 'irodeferred'
                    ,renderer : this.linkiroRenderer
                },
                {
                    id       :'totcallsentered',
                    header   : ' Total Calls Entered', 
                    width    : 100, 
                    sortable : true, 
                    dataIndex : 'totcallsentered',
                    renderer : this.linkRenderer
                },
                {
                    id       :'totfollowup',
                    header   : ' Follow Up', 
                    width    : 100, 
                    sortable : true, 
                    dataIndex: 'totfollowup',
                    renderer : this.linkRenderer
                },
                {
                    id       :'totcallback',
                    header   : ' Call Backs', 
                    width    : 100, 
                    sortable : true, 
                    dataIndex: 'totcallback',
                    renderer : this.linkRenderer
                },
                {
                    id       :'totnotintrested',
                    header   : ' Not Interested', 
                    width    : 100, 
                    sortable : true, 
                    dataIndex: 'totnotintrested',
                    renderer : this.linkRenderer
                },
                {
                    id       :'totdealsclosed',
                    header   : ' Deals Closed', 
                    width    : 100, 
                    sortable : true, 
                    dataIndex: 'totdealsclosed',
                    renderer : this.linkRenderer
                },
                 {
                    id       :'totresellerregistered',
                    header   : ' Reseller Registered', 
                    width    : 100, 
                    sortable : true, 
                    dataIndex: 'totresellerregistered',
                    renderer : this.linkRenderer
                }
            ]
          ,plugins :[]
          ,viewConfig :{forceFit:true}
          ,tbar :[]
          ,bbar :[]
          ,height : 350
          ,width : 1060
           ,title : 'Reseller Dashboard'

        }; // eo config object

        // apply config
        Ext.apply(this, Ext.apply(this.initialConfig, config));

        Application.DashBoardGrid.superclass.initComponent.apply(this, arguments);
    } // eo function initComponent
    /** 
    * It is the renderer of the links of cell 
    * @param data  value of cell 
    * @param record  object of data has all the data of store and record.id is unique 
    **/
    ,linkRenderer : function (data, cell, record, rowIndex, columnIndex, store) {
        var tag={ 
            tag: 'a',
            href: '#', 
            html: data//, 
            // onclick: this.resellerWindow(record.data.cityname,cell.id) 
        };

         if  (data != null)  {
            return '<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="resellerwindow(\'' +record.data.cityname+'\',\''+cell.id+'\',\''+this.header+'\')">'+ data +'</a>';
        }
        return data;
    }
    /** 
    * It is the renderer of the links iro's column of cell 
    * @param data  value of cell 
    * @param record  object of data has all the data of store and record.id is unique 
    **/
    ,linkiroRenderer : function (data, cell, record, rowIndex, columnIndex, store) {
        // console.log(this.header);
         if  (data != null)  {
            return '<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="resellerirowindow(\'' +record.data.cityname+'\',\''+cell.id+'\',\''+this.header+'\')">'+ data +'</a>';
        }
        return data;
    }
   ,resellerwindow : function (cityname,columndataindex) {
        var win = new Ext.Window({
            items:{
                xtype : 'ResellerGrid',
                'cityname' : cityname,
                'columndataindex' : columndataindex
             }
        });
        win.show();
    }
    ,onRender:function() {
        // this.store.load();
        Application.DashBoardGrid.superclass.onRender.apply(this, arguments);
    } // eo function onRender
});

Ext.reg('DashBoardGrid', Application.DashBoardGrid);
```

This is my json returned

```
{
    "countothercities": "1",
    "directreseller": "24",
    "totalresellersregisteredfor8cities": 23,
    "cityarray": [{
        "cityname": "bangalore",
        "totfollowup": "2",
        "totcallback": "3",
        "totnotintrested": "1",
        "totdealsclosed": "0",
        "totcallsreceived": "0",
        "totcallsentered": "88",
        "totresellerregistered": "4",
        "countiro": "156",
        "irotransferred": "130",
        "irodeferred": "26"
    }
}
```

how Can i show the

"countothercities": "1",
        "directreseller": "24",
        "totalresellersregisteredfor8cities": 23,

below the grid ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access this data via

```
var countothercities = grid.getStore().reader.jsonData.countothercities;
var directreseller = grid.getStore().reader.jsonData.directreseller;
var totalresellersregisteredfor8cities = grid.getStore().reader.jsonData. totalresellersregisteredfor8cities;
```

How you would output this data greatly depends on your UI.

To get hold on this data when the store has been loaded, you perhaps should add an event listener to the `load`-event on your store, e.g. add this to your `initComponent()`  method:

```
store.on('load', function(s) {
    var countothercities = s.reader.jsonData.countothercities;
    var directreseller = s.reader.jsonData.directreseller;
    var totalresellersregisteredfor8cities = s.reader.jsonData. totalresellersregisteredfor8cities;
}, this);
```

Now you can do whatever you want with your three variables.

**EDIT**

To add the data to the bottom toolbar of your grid change the line `,bbar :[]` to

```
,bbar: [{
    xtype: 'tbtext',
    ref: 'status',
    text: ''
}]
```

This will add an empty `Ext.Toolbar.TextItem` to your bottom bar.

```
store.on('load', function(s) {
    var countothercities = s.reader.jsonData.countothercities;
    var directreseller = s.reader.jsonData.directreseller;
    var totalresellersregisteredfor8cities = s.reader.jsonData. totalresellersregisteredfor8cities;

    this.getBottomToolbar().status.setText(String.format('{0}, {1}, {2}', 
        countothercities, 
        directreseller,
        totalresellersregisteredfor8cities
    ));
}, this);
```

Comment: nice the variable values are coming how i can put them below the grid , can i put in the bbar

Comment: the bottom bar is coming blank , why you used status `ref` and you are assigning to status ?

Comment: Oops - sorry missed the `setText()`. I fixed the example code. This code makes use of the `ref`-concept within the Ext components which allows you to register properties for your components on the appropriate container. That's why we can use `toolbar.status` to access our text item component.